# How to use Select in ReactJS, and creating its options with an Array

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to ReactJS. Well I only want to solve this problem, nothing else I want from React. In my already build app, SelectField (of Material-UI) is used, which do not show the selected value. Other than this everything works fine. Here is the Markup:

```
<SelectField ref="device" selectedIndex={this.state.deviceIndex} displayMember="device_model" valueMember="device_id" menuItems={this.state.devices} onChange={this.onSelectDevice} style={{float:"left", marginTop:"5px", width:"300px"}} />
```

I want one of the two things:
1. Either solve my problem with the existing SelectField component, after which I will be able to get the selected item. OR
2. Share the method of working with simple HTML Select...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must pass the menu items to display as children to the SelectField component. This is easy with an inline mapping expression.

Example:

```
  <SelectField selectedIndex={this.state.deviceIndex}>
    {this.state.devices.map(device =>
      <MenuItem value={device.id} primaryText={device.name}/>
    )}
  </SelectField>
```

Comment: In the console, it gives an error: 
Uncaught ReferenceError: MenuItem is not defined

Comment: You need to import it somehow, I don't know what module system you are using. The documentation is a great resource: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/select-field

Comment: can we do this with simple HTML Select?

Comment: Sure, you just replace SelectField with select, and MenuItem with option.